# Netbeans 7.2 Missing Modules Warning

Tags: 12.04, netbeans, jdk

Everytime I start Netbeans and the splash screen shows up when it gets to the part to load the modules I receive the following error message :

> Warning - could not install some modules: Editor Library 2 - None of the modules providing the capability org.netbeans.modules.editor.actions could be installed. Tags Based Editors Library - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting/0-1 was needed and not found. Java Editor Library - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting/0-1 was needed and not found. Preprocessor Bridge - None of the modules providing the capability org.netbeans.modules.java.preprocessorbridge.spi.JavaSourceUtilImpl could be installed. Freeform Ant Projects - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent.project/0-1 was needed and not found. Editor Code Templates - The module named org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0-1 was needed and not found. Static Analysis Core - The module named org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0-1 was needed and not found. Java Source - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent.project/0-1 was needed and not found. Eclipse Project Importer - The module named org.netbeans.modules.java.api.common/0-1 was needed and not found. Java Hints SPI - The module named org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0-1 was needed and not found. Java Refactoring - The module named org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0-1 was needed and not found. Java Editor - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.bracesmatching/0-1 was needed and not found. Java Editor - The module named org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0-1 was needed and not found. Java Editor - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting/0-1 was needed and not found. Java Hints UI - The module named org.netbeans.modules.code.analysis/0-1 was needed and not found. Java Hints UI - The module named org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0-1 was needed and not found. Legacy Java Hints SPI - The module named org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0-1 was needed and not found. Java Hints - The module named org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0-1 was needed and not found. Java Declarative Hints - The module named org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0-1 was needed and not found. Javadoc - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.bracesmatching/0-1 was needed and not found. Javadoc - The module named org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0-1 was needed and not found. Common Scripting Language API (new) - The module named org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0-1 was needed and not found. XML Text Editor - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.bracesmatching/0-1 was needed and not found. XML Text Editor - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting/0-1 was needed and not found. CSS Editor - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.bracesmatching/0-1 was needed and not found. HTML Editor - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.bracesmatching/0-1 was needed and not found. JavaScript Editing - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.bracesmatching/0-1 was needed and not found. JavaScript Hints - The module named org.netbeans.spi.editor.hints/0-1 was needed and not found. Editing Files - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.bracesmatching/0-1 was needed and not found. IDE Platform - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.macros/0-1 was needed and not found. Java SE Projects - The module named org.netbeans.modules.java.api.common/0-1 was needed and not found. 86 further modules could not be installed due to the above problems.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the window that shows up everytime I start Netbeans]

Whatever I press either `Exit` or `Disable Modules and Continue` or even I close from the `"X" Button` the Warning window closes and then Netbeans never starts.

I have looked it up on the Internet,but I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the 7.1.2 version and it seems to work a lot better than the 7.2.In fact,it is working perfectly.I do not know if this happened only in my system or happened in other systems as well.After a small google research it seems that many people are blaming the Auto Updater of Netbeans for those kind of errors.